# Is "what more is you looking for" correct?

Tags: verbs

While I sing a song "Under the sea" to my baby, I found a weird sentence.

> The seaweed is always greener in somebody else's lake
>   You dream about going up there but that is a big mistake
>   Just look at the world around you, right here on the ocean floor.
>   Such wonderful things surround you, what more **is** you looking for?

Isn't it should be "what more **are** you looking for"? 
I know lyrics are not always correct in grammar but.. Can you guess the reason behind? Is there a rhyme?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request about non-standard lyrics.

Answer (score 3):

In the movie, this song is sung by Sebastian, who has a Carribean accent. It's not uncommon in the Carribean dialect of English (which shares some traits with African-American English) to use "is" instead of "are".

You can find the same thing in "Porgy and Bess", in the song "Bess, You Is My Woman Now".

Comment: Or as an alternative to @Barmar's point, a register in which "you" is considered a singular form (where "you all" would refer to more-than-one-"you" in some [geographic and social] varieties of American English).  This is a trait (usefully) shared by AAVE and Glasgow English -- in the later, it would be "you"/"youze (yins)".  AAVE and Glasgow retain a helpful analogue to the older Standard English "thou" (singular) / "you" (plural) distinction.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear. I always thought that "You" & "are" should stick together at all time. But I could think of singular you and plural you now. Thanks.    Thanks Barmar, thanks Robin :)

Comment: @Rachel In standard English, it's "you are". But these songs aren't in standard English, they're in a creole dialect.

Comment: You could say that, but then you'd have to say that (Received) Standard (American/British) English is **also** a dialect, albeit one which is socially privileged and generally used in formal written texts and certain social situations. As they say, a language is simply a dialect with an army on its side. Also, strictly, a creole is (roughly) a blend of more than one language, whereas a dialect is simply a regional or social variant of a single base language. How about "colloquial spoken Trinidadian"?